# How do i enable compiz widget layer onto ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installed-programs

I installed the **compiz** package but when i added widgets via screenlets there was no layer.

i want a layer so it would look like the mac version.

how do I do this?

I have looked into the setting but could not find it, it might be there but i could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is installing the extra package.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Comment: thanks. where did you find this thread it is so old now.